# Definition of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here is the defintion of discrete random variable from "An introduction to probability and statistics" by Rohatgi.

> Let $(\Omega,S,P)$ be a probability space. An random variable $X$ defined on this space is said to be discrete if there exists a countable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $P\{X\in E\} = 1$

I am not too sure about this definition, since it seems more natural to me that for $X$ to be discrete, $X(\Omega)$ is a countable set. Isn't it possible that $X(\Omega)$ is uncountable, but there is some countable set $E$ such that $P\{X\in E\}=1$? In this case, above definition would call $X$ discrete, although $X$ is not "discrete".

Is the above definition wrong? or am I missing something?

Comment: $P(X=E)$ is strange. Perhaps you have $P(X\in E)=1$. You, please check.

Comment: It is certainly possible that $X(\Omega) = \{X(\omega) : \omega \in \Omega\}$ be uncountable, but if there exists a countable $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(X \in E) = 1$, then $P(X \in X(\Omega)\setminus E) = 0$. In other words, $X$ has probability 0 of taking any of the other "uncountably many" values, so they do not matter and $X$ is essentially discrete. Edit: Also, $ P(\Omega)$? You mean $ X(\Omega)$?

Comment: @zoli Just editted, sorry for the typo

Comment: @snarski My bad! so many typos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because most of the time we identify functions which are almost surely equal. The whole theory of Lebesgue spaces carries this identifications, and for good reasons; there are a lot of properties that hold; for example we have

$X = Y \ a.s. \implies E(X) = E(Y)$

In general we don't care too much about sets of measure zero; many theorem only prove things "outside of a set of measure 0", and that is because many properties cease to be true when we want them to hold for every point.

Anyhow the point is that since what we care about is the set where $X$ lies almost always,instead of requiring $X$ to take on only countable values, it's natural to weaken that condition and allow $X$ to take on *almost always* values in a countable set.